# New to MiKTeX: Errors when updating and compiling

Tags: miktex, windows

I've just migrated from MacTeX (on 10.7) to MiKTeX 2.9 (Windows 7) and I'm getting some pretty nonproductive errors.

I'm using the "Basic" MiKTeX install (via `basic-miktex-2.9.4407.exe`) and I have not manually altered the distribution in any way. This is a completely out-of-the-box install.

Whenever I try to update MiKTeX via the "Update" program, I get the following error:

```
The operation could not be completed for the following reason:
Windows API error 5: Access is denied.
Details: C:\
```

When I try to install a package that I don't currently have, I get the following error:

```
pdflatex.EXE: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.
```

Basically, whenever I try to do anything in MiKTeX I get some flavor of the `Windows API error 5: Access is denied.` error.

Further searching/Googling of the internet and document hasn't yielded any specific results or potential fixes.

I'm new to Windows (and MiKTeX, for that matter), so I'm kind of puzzled on what's going on and how to fix it.

Comment: What happens when you run that stuff as admin? Just a wild guess.

Comment: I guess you have installed MikTeX with a user login that does not have admin priviledges.

Comment: I've installed MiKTeX only under my account. I'm the only account on the computer and I'm the administrator.

Comment: I think I've fixed the problem. Although I'm the administrator, Windows isn't set to run applications with administrator privileges. Setting the program to do so manually seems to fix the problem.